# How to combine multiple feature points array in a single one

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In a single frame I have already detected multiple face via facecascade.
I have also applied a loop to determine `p0` for each face via `goodFeaturesToTrack`. Now I want to combine all those `p0` so that I can pass it as an argument to `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` function:

```
for (x, y, w, h) in first_faces:
    cv2.rectangle(first_frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    roi_first_gray = first_gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(roi_first_gray, mask=None, maxCorners=200, qualityLevel=0.1, minDistance=7, blockSize=7)
```

Now here for every face in `first_faces` a `p0` like for first face it is:

```
[[[ 479.  319.]]
 [[ 407.  373.]] 
 [[ 334.  387.]] 
 [[ 343.  371.]] 
 [[ 369.  369.]]]
```

Type of this is `numpy.ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy.concatenate

```
import numpy as np
p0 = np.array([[[479.0, 319.0]],
               [[407.0, 373.0]],
               [[334.0, 387.0]],
               [[343.0, 371.0]],
               [[369.0, 369.0]]])
p1 = np.array([[[279.0, 119.0]],
               [[207.0, 173.0]],
               [[134.0, 187.0]],
               [[143.0, 171.0]],
               [[169.0, 169.0]]])
print(np.concatenate((p0, p1), axis=0))
print(np.concatenate((p0, p1), axis=1))
```

I don't know what format of info you require for the opencv functions or why your array has an extra dimension.

Comment: In what way didn't it work. i.e. does the program crash with an error message? Does it run but not track any faces? Does it run but only track the first face? What happens if you just use p0 from the 1st face in the image, or the 2nd, or 3rd i.e. don't attempt to concatenate them? What do you get if you print the shape of the p0 array for each individual face and after attempting to concatenating them?